# Send SMS using SmsManager in android fail in some device

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, smsmanager

I try to send message using SmsManager in android i use this code in my application it work fine only some of the device it is not working.
i just make one class for send message

```
  public class Sms {
    public static final String TAG = "Sms";

    public void sendSms(String number, String message) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Sending " + message + " to " + number);

        if (message.length() > 159) {
            message = message.substring(0, 159);
        }

          SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage(number, null, message, null,null);

    }
}
```

this class is for send message
 i am send using below code

```
buddys = db.getAllContacts();

                for (int i = 0; i < buddys.size(); i++) {
                    Sms sms = new Sms();
                    sms.sendSms(buddys.get(i).getPhoneNumber(), msg_);
                    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), ""+msg_+" to "+buddys.get(i).getPhoneNumber(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

numbers are come from database there are maximum 4 number. it is **working fine** in **gionee , sony , and micromax , and Moto g**  But **not working** in **samsung device and zenfone** . i put the toast for test it also toast the message in all the devices  but the problem is only not send the message. i reused the size of message to 160 i think that was the problem but again same problem is occurs please help me.

Comment: what does it gives error or exception, would you please post.

Comment: @Akshay it will not give any error it was not send SMS . i debug my app but didn't get any error and this code is also working in gionee , sony , and micromax , and Moto g as i describe in question.

Comment: i think you show change your code , because for message of above 159 c , it didn't work

Comment: @adnan9011 i already remove the char more then 159 using  if (message.length() > 159) {
            message = message.substring(0, 159);
        }

Comment: @adnan9011 i already remove the char more then 159 using  if (message.length() > 159) {
            message = message.substring(0, 159);
        }

Comment: The SMS length check has no meaning if you don't strip away accents as well. I could write 160 "ů"s and get away with it even if it doesn't fit one message.

Comment: @Sagar Devani , change 159 to 158 . this is really big problem . :)

Comment: @adnan9011 Change where (2 occurences)? Why would it be a problem? If it's shorter than 160, it's ok. If it's larger, it will take first 160 chars.

Comment: @Eugen Pechanec , you right . but we must be sure to our code that work correctly . becuse this code is correct for some device and not working for another .

Comment: @adnan9011  Eugen Pechanec it is not working on samsung grand 2. and length is not problem i reduce to 160.